# pass created model object in one test method to next one in EcomDev PHPUnit

Tags: ecomdev-phpunit

Need to create test for custom creating product and custom editing product methods.
I use fixtures for both methods with same user data and want to pass freshly created product in first method to second, how can i achieve it ?

Creating product :

```
    /**
     * Test Add New Service Controller
     * @test
     * @loadFixture
     * @group testor
     */
    public function addNewServiceTest()
    {
        ...
        $this->getRequest()->setMethod('POST')->setPost($mockPostDataForNewService);
        $this->dispatch($addNewServiceRoute);
        ...
        $responseDecoded = json_decode($response);
        $createdProductId = $responseDecoded->id;
        $createdProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($createdProductId);
        return $createdProduct;
    }

    /**
     * Test proper editing of created product
     * @test
     * @group testor
     * @loadFixture
     * @depends addNewServiceTest
     */
    public function editServiceTest($createdProduct) {

        $createdProduct->save(); // save seems like done ok, but all 
        Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getItems(); // still returns only fixture products, but not saved one

    }
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: What makes you say "save seems like done ok"? It's probably doing nothing because `$_hasDataChanges` is false. Try `$createdProduct->setDataChanges(true)->save()` instead.

Comment: Thank you, Fabian, it really did not save the model , `_hasDataChanges=true` seems like fixed the issues with saving, but another one occurred - some attributes did not saved. In first test, all attributes saves (in fact, they are saving fine in magento' product model script) fine but when i try to get that attributes in second test - they just missing. Can it be caused by scope (i am calling the model in scope of the test, and try to get these attributes in test as well )?

Comment: I am not sure if this is related to what you describe, but there might be problems due to `@loadFixture` in your second test. Can you remove it? I have to say that I did try working with `@depends` in EcomDev_PHPUnit once as well and found it to be difficult. So I would just merge these two test into a single one.